# jQuery scroll activated content to element

Tags: jquery

I am working on a staff page where the staff photos are in a grid on one side of the page and bios are displayed in a column to the other side. I am using jQuery to add active class when staff are clicked and also uses `.position()` to set the css for the bio positioning. All this works perfect except the first item on page load. I have added a class of active to the first staff member, but I cannot get the `.position()` to work properly on page load. It seems to only work on `'click()`

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#team-list li a').click(function() {
    $('#team-list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
    var pos = $(this).parentsUntil('#team-list').position();
    var width = $(this).parent('#container').outerWidth();
    $("#team-list .active .bio").css({
      left: - + (pos.left + width) + "px"
    })
    return false;
  });
});
```

I have tried adding the following in a separate function:

```
$(function() {
  var initialPos = $('#team-list').position();
  var initialWidth = $('#container').outerWidth();
  $("#team-list .active .bio").css({
    left: - + (initialPos.left + initialWidth) + "px"
  })
});
```

I have tried this in a couple of variations using `.load()` and `.ready()`
This is a wordpress site so it must start with the `jQuery(document).ready(function()`

EDIT: Added HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="team-list">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">
              <img>
              <h3>Person 1</h3>
            </a>
        <div class="bio">
          <h3>Person 1</h3>
          <h4>President</h4>
          <p>
            Person 1 bio
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
              <img>
              <h3>Person 2</h3>
            </a>
        <div class="bio">
          <h3>Person 2</h3>
          <h4>Vice President</h4>
          <p>
            Person 2 bio
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
              <img>
              <h3>Person 3</h3>
            </a>
        <div class="bio">
          <h3>Person 3</h3>
          <h4>Secretary</h4>
          <p>
            Person 3 bio
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
              <img>
              <h3>Person 4</h3>
            </a>
        <div class="bio">
          <h3>Person 4</h3>
          <h4>COO</h4>
          <p>
            Person 4 bio
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
              <img>
              <h3>Person 5</h3>
            </a>
        <div class="bio">
          <h3>Person 5</h3>
          <h4>CEO</h4>
          <p>
            Person 5 bio
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
              <img>
              <h3>Person 6</h3>
            </a>
        <div class="bio">
          <h3>Person 6</h3>
          <h4>CFO</h4>
          <p>
            Person 6 bio
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.container {
  max-width: 1040px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#team-list {
  width: 66.66667%;
  margin-left: 33.33333%;
}

#team-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#team-list li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#team-list li:nth-child(odd) {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#team-list li:nth-child(even) {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#team-list .bio {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 80%;
}

#team-list .active .bio {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: can you also include a short version of your HTML? like in a [mcve] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you establish the click handler, emulate a click on the first item.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#team-list li a').click(function() {
    $('#team-list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');  
    var pos = $(this).parentsUntil('#team-list').position();
    var width = $(this).parent('#container').outerWidth();
    $("#team-list .active .bio").css({
      left: - + (pos.left + width) + "px"
    })
    return false;
  }).eq(0).click();
});
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks!